# Шаблоны (параметры шаблонов)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, что можно использовать в качестве параметра типа шаблона? Спасибо!

**Добавлено.**

Вот что сделал пока...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

template <class Qtype> 
class q_type {
    Qtype a; // содержит очередь
public:
    q_type():a(0){}
};

void main(){
    q_type<char> q2;
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Тип параметра шаблона может быть любым**, главное, чтобы при подстановке шаблон скомпилировался *(с учетом применения соответствующих `resolution rules`).*

---

Для того, чтобы разбираться в этих самых правилах подстановки, рекомендую к прочтению [*C++ Templates - The Complete Guide.*](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/)

Кстати говоря, в `C++` есть и другие интересные механизмы, например, [*SFINAE*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) который лежит в основе [`boost::enable_if`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html)

Answer (score -2):

Все стандартные типы данных - такие как int, char... Насчет классов и структур не уверен, по-моему их нельзя.

Comment: Можно ссылки...., но на какие типы и как????

Comment: Можете пример кода со ссылкой дать???
вот что сделал пока...
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

template <class Qtype> 
class q_type {
 Qtype a; // содержит очередь
public:
 q_type():a(0){}
};


void main(){

 q_type<срфк> q2;


 getch();
}

Comment: Все можно, только осторожно.